# mysql update to colum 3 condition from same table

Tags: mysql

this my table

```
kwh       p1 p2 p3 period
2         0  0  0  201408
15        0  0  0  201408
25        0  0  0  201408
```

i want to update p1.p2.p3 with this condition

```
UPDATE t.mytable
SET 
    c.p1 = if (c.kwh <= 10,c.kwh * 1600,c.p1),
    c.p2 = if (c.kwh <= 20,c.kwh * 2285,c.p2),
    c.p3 = if (c.kwh => 21,c.kwh - 20 * 3195,p.3),
WHERE
    c.period = '082015'
```

please help

Comment: So what is the issue you are facing with the update command ?

Comment: What table/object does `c.` refer to? and `p.3` in last set statement?  maybe `c.p3`?

Comment: For starters, fix all the syntax errors: (1) get rid of the `t.` and `c.` and `p.` stuff, (2) get rid of the comma at the end of the fifth line, (3) on the fifth line also change the `=>` to `>=`.

Comment: Consider normalising your design.